# Python Dictionary: How to get the longest key for the longest value?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dic = {'a':4, 'b':5, 'cd':5 }
```

I'm trying to find:

- highest value (search for the highest value first => `b`, `cd`)
- longest key   (then search for the longest key => `'cd'`)

I use the following code:

```
max_val = dic[max(dic, key=dic.get)]
maxDicVal = dict(filter(lambda x: x[1] == max_val, dic.items()))
maxDicKey = max(maxDicVal, key=len)
```

Is there any better way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can then sort the dictionary items based on the value descending followed by the length of the key descending. For example:

```py
items = sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda v:(v[1], len(v[0])), reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
[('cd', 5), ('b', 5), ('a', 4)]
```

The `maxDicKey` is then `items[0][0]` i.e. `cd`

Comment: I didnt know that the key can have multiple conditions.  Thanks for the knowledge.  I counldnt find the information on this.  If you have the link to the python documentation, would be glad if you could post here for me.  If not, that's fine too !  Thanks again.

Comment: @EBDS there is only really one condition, but that condition is a tuple, which python sorts on the first value and then the second. So this sorts all the entries by the values (the first part of the tuple), and for equal values sorts by the key length (the second part of the tuple0. The tuple can be of arbitrary length so you can sort on as many different parameters as you like.

Comment: ic.  Didn't know I can do that.  Thanks again for your help... !!!

Answer (score 2):

**A big improvement**

---

We really should try to do everything in one pass. The downside is that there is more code. The following stores the first key in `dic` in `cur`, then iterates through `dic`, starting from the second key, updating `cur` if we find a value that is greater than the value associated with the key `cur` or if we find a key, value pair with value equal to the value associated with the key `cur` and the length of the key is greater than the length of `cur`.

```
it = iter(dic)
cur = next(it)        # the first key
for key in it:        # iterate thr keys of dic, starting from second
    if dic[key] > dic[cur] or (dic[key] == dic[cur] and len(key) > len(cur)):
        cur = key

print(cur)
```

**A smaller improvement**

---

```
max_value = max(dic.values())
a = max((k for k in dic if dic[k] == max_value), key = len)
```

`(k for k in dic if dic[k] == max_value)` is a generator that yields keys in `dic` such that its value is equal to the maximum value. `max(..., key = len)` then chooses the largest string amongst those keys.

The above is faster than this one-liner as the above caches `max(dic.values())`:

```
a = max((k for k in dic if dic[k] == max(dic.values())), key = len)
```

**Timings**

---

```
# EBDS 
1.19 µs ± 3.26 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

# oda (a smaller improvement)
759 ns ± 4.12 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

# oda (a big improvement)
304 ns ± 0.953 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

# Nick
648 ns ± 1.36 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the time testing.  I really appreciate the effort.  But it's a bit complicated for me to use for the time being.  Thanks again !

Comment: Thanks.  I wonder where the time savings come from.  It is because in the I did a dict() 2 times, taking up time to create the dict ?  I see that in your first answer, you create a iterator and not any dict.  In the 2nd case, you created a tuple (one time only).